# How can I get IntelliJ to use tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have gone to File, Settings; in there to Editor, Code Style, Java. And in there I have set use tab character and smart tabs.

But in the editor it keeps inserting 4 spaces instead of tabs. How can I get tabs?

[image]

Comment: You need to reformat your code then you will able to get tab instead of space

Comment: @MKTan I tried that - still does spaces.

Comment: Do you see this behaviour for existing files only or for new files as well? Does disabling EditorConfig and Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** help?

Comment: @Andrey That was it - thank you! If you make that an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an `.editorconfig` file this will override your IDE code style settings.
You can disable it by unchecking the tickbox 'Enable EditorConfig support' under *Editor* > *Code Style*.
[Tabs and Indents - Intellij Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000155024-Settings-Tabs-and-Indents)

Comment: That was checked and I unchecked it. But I still get spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** option.